# Jackson databind - how to deserialize an object without specifying the target class?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am migrating from snakeyaml and a feature snakeyaml had is that it automatically wrote the object type in the output YAML so that deserialization would be transparent and easy.  I cannot seem to find the same feature in Jackson Databind.

If I merely specify Object.class, I get a LinkedHashMap which is to be expected.  Additionally, for this to work, I would have to see the class type in the JSON and I haven't found a native way to do that.

Is this required?

Comment: Until then I will have a field store the class I'm serializing, then read the data back to a map, look for that field, then from that get the type and finally rerun the import with that :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up prepending the class name before the actual object data and then split that out prior to actually deserializing the data back into an object which is what snakeyaml does automatically.  I was hoping to do this automatically in Jackson though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly perhaps you are looking for [JsonTypeInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)

From the docs

```
  // Include Java class name ("com.myempl.ImplClass") as JSON property "class"
  @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
```

Comment: That looks like what I want, let me try it :).

Comment: I apparently must also need to do something when reading it back in as I just got a LinkedHashMap as well.  The other problem with this approach for me is that I don't want my code depending on Jackson since I want to support both Jackson and Snakeyaml (and maybe something else).  That said, This JsonTypeInfo annotation does get the metadata written, but I wonder if I could programmatically do the same by configuring the object mapper.